# Cannot install Snort 2.9.6.1 due to "Not a compatible architecture"

Tags: centos, rpm, snort

I have Centos 6.5 installed on a Dell Inspirion Intel chip.  When I entered

```
uname -a
```

I got

```
Linux family.room 2.6.32-431.el6.i686 #1 SMP Fri Nov 22 00:26:36 UTC 2013 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

I tried the following commands after downlowning the appropriate .rpm file.

```
sudo yum localinstall snort-2.9.6.1-1.f19.x86_64.rpm
sudo yum localinstall snort-2.9.6.1-1.centos6.x86_64.rpm
sudo yum localinstall snort-2.9.6.0-1.src.rpm
```

In every case, the response was

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
Setting up Local Package Process
Examining snort-2.9.6.1-1.f19.x86_64.rpm: 1:snort-2.9.6.1-1.x86_64
Cannot add package snort-2.9.6.1-1.f19.x86_64.rpm to transaction. Not a compatible architecture: x86_64
Nothing to do
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to install a 64-bit package (`x86_64`) on a 32-bit system (note the `i686` in `uname -a`) which is not going to work. You need to look for snort packages that have either `i686.rpm` or `x86.rpm` at the end. I would tell you what exactly to look for but I don't have any appropriate CentOS systems around at this time, sorry :)

Or install a 64-bit version of CentOS (if your hardware supports it).